# File found on PySpark but not found in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

When I try this

```
filePath1='/tmp/cs/data_train/cs_subsprofile.csv'
fd_subsprofile=spark.read.format("csv").schema(schema_f_d_subs_profile).load(filePath1)
```

or

```
fd_subsprofile = spark.read.csv('/tmp/cs/data_train/cs_subsprofile.csv', header = True)
```

it is successful, but when I try

`data = pd.read_csv('/tmp/cs/data_train/cs_subsprofile.csv')`

The result is

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/cs/data_train/cs_subsprofile.csv'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spark probably not reading from **local file system**, but from a **distributed file system** (such as HDFS). Pandas **only** read from local file system and that's the reason why it cannot find the file.